# Is an expression like 3600 * 24 evaluated at compile-time?

Tags: scala

In Scala, suppose I write

```
val oneDay = 3600L * 24 // seconds in one day
val twoDay = oneDay * 2 // seconds in two days
```

Is the final value of `oneDay` (i.e., `86400`) computed at runtime or compile-time?

What about the final value of `twoDay`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be sure of the final values, I try to compile your code using:

```
scalac main.scala -Xprint:all
```

And, in the last phase, your code turn to be:

```
final <synthetic> def delayedEndpoint$Main$1: Unit = {
      Main.this.oneDay = 86400L;
      Main.this.twoDay = Main.this.oneDay().*(2);
      ()
    };
```

So, the first value is computed at compile-time but the second value will be computed at runtime.

With Scala 3.0 it is possible to use `inline` (or `final` as stated by @ghik) to make also the second value computed at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `3600L * 24` will be constant-folded and computed in compile time.

As for `oneDay * 2`, it depends on how `oneDay` is declared. If it's something like this:

```scala
object Constants {
  // note the `final` keyword and *no* explicit type
  final val oneDay = 3600L * 24

  val twoDay = oneDay * 2
}
```

then references to `oneDay` will also be seen as constants by the compiler and constant-folded.